# Bash array grouping elements

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm trying to create an array that looks like this:

```
0       kernel
1       /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 
2       kernel
3       /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

Using the grubby command of which the ouput for the entires I'm looking for are:

```
index=2
kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
root=/dev/mapper/<my_vol>-root
initrd=/boot/initramfs-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.img
title=CentOS Linux (4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64) 7 (Core)
index=3
kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
root=/dev/mapper/<my_vol>-root
initrd=/boot/initramfs-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.img
title=CentOS Linux (4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64) 7 (Core)
```

(I've removed the "args=" line for sanitisation purposes)

When I try to use the following command which works... (err... for the first 2 elements of the array). It decided that 2 indicies should be squashed into one.

```
IFS='=' read -a KERNELS <<< $(sudo grubby --info=ALL |grep -v rescue |grep -E 4.[78] |grep kernel)

0       kernel
1       /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 kernel
2       /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

First of why is it doing this? And how can I fix it?

I understand that there are other ways I could solve this problem but I want to understand what's going on here:

```
for i in ${KERNELS[@]}; do echo $i; done
kernel
/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
kernel
/boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

for i in ${!KERNELS[@]}; do echo $i ${KERNELS[$i]}; done
0 kernel
1 /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 kernel
2 /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that when you run

```
sudo grubby --info=ALL |grep -v rescue |grep -E 4.[78] |grep kernel
kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

You get two lines of output and the IFS= is separating on '=' and ignoring the '\n'

I've tried using `awk '{print}' ORS=' '` ideas to output everything on one line but it gets messy.

There has to be a more elegant way to use the hereto string with multiple lines of output. Surely...

Comment: yup I sure can.

Comment: As an aside, the long `grep` pipeline seems to beg for an Awk solution.  `grubby --info=ALL | awk 'BEGIN { ORS="=" } !/rescue/ && /4\.[78]/ && /kernel/'` -- notice also the requirement to backslash a literal period, and see also [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions: `for i in ${!KERNELS[@]}; do echo "$i" "${KERNELS[i]}"; done`. You'll see that `${KERNELS[1]}` contains the newline that separates the two lines in the output of the pipeline. A here-string isn't appropriate here. (Also, what version of `bash` are you using? A bug dealing with pre-command environment settings and here-strings that wasn't completely fixed until `bash` 4.4 may be affecting your results.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use process substitution combined with `read` directive:

```
arr=()

while IFS='=' read -r k v; do
   [[ $k = "kernel" ]] && { arr+=("$k"); arr+=("$v"); }
done < <(sudo grubby --info=ALL)
```

Check array content:

```
printf '[%s]\n' "${arr[@]}"

[kernel]
[/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64]
[kernel]
[/boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I accidently just has a moment of clarity using the exta info posted above

```
IFS='=' read -a KERNELS <<< $(sudo grubby --info=ALL |grep -v rescue |grep -E 4.[78] |grep kernel | awk '{print}' ORS='=')

for i in ${!KERNELS[@]}; do echo ${KERNELS[$i]} $i; done
kernel 0
/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 1
kernel 2
/boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 3
```

I've used awk to get around the fact that there are multiple lines with terminating '\n' and instead inserted a '=' which will be the delimiting factor in building the array. =]

Comment: You don't really need to use 2 `grep` commands and one `awk` after `grubby` command to parse it out. Just a single `awk` can handle it all.

Comment: I know this. But since unix pipes, unix programs, and the unix paradigm in general is based on small, simple pieces chained together, why would I replace 3 simple easily readable/editable stages for ascii vomit I'm going to have to groan at in 6 months. Also I have other problems to solve ^_^ but thanks for your input!

Comment: It's your choice but in case your input is big than invoking 3 external calls will hurt you big time while processing.